# KOGrid is not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to make KO Grid to work. I am in Ko 2.1 environment and I am trying to use Ko grid with it in an MVC view. Weird thing is that when I load my page, i do not see anythign at all. I have a fiddle file which renders the frid absolutely fine:http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/sf4p3/14/

My code is very much similar: But that is failing to render at all.

My HTMl is as below:

```
<div id="KoGridContainer">
    <div data-bind="koGrid: { data: Prizefillfilmentstatuses }"></div>

    <button id="Get" data-bind="click:GetAll">Get</button>
    <p><span data-bind='text: Prizefillfilmentstatuses().length'>&nbsp;</span> row(s)</p>


</div>
```

and my Js code looks as below:

```
 function ($, ui, ko, komapping, servicesConfig, constants, koGrid) {
        $("#body").fadeIn();
        var self = {};

        self.ViewModel = {

            GetAll: function () {
                self.getAll();
            },

            Prizefillfilmentstatuses: ko.observableArray([
                { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', createdOn: '1/1/2012', birthday: '1/1/1977', salary: 40000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Harper', createdOn: '1/2/2012', birthday: '2/1/1976', salary: 45000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Carrey', createdOn: '1/3/2012', birthday: '3/1/1985', salary: 60000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'DiMaggio', createdOn: '1/4/2012', birthday: '4/1/1991', salary: 70000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jeff', lastName: 'Saturday', createdOn: '1/5/2012', birthday: '5/1/1998', salary: 65000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Marg', lastName: 'Simpson', createdOn: '1/6/2012', birthday: '6/1/1921', salary: 20000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Tim', lastName: 'Allen', createdOn: '1/7/2012', birthday: '7/1/1977', salary: 35000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Kevin', lastName: 'Bacon', createdOn: '1/8/2012', birthday: '8/1/1977', salary: 30000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Murphy', createdOn: '1/9/2012', birthday: '9/1/1999', salary: 55000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jessica', lastName: 'Smith', createdOn: '1/10/2012', birthday: '10/1/1979', salary: 45000 }
            ])
        };

//        if ($("#KoGridContainer").length == 1) {
//            $.consolelog("found Ko-Grid");
//            ko.applyBindings(self.ViewModel, $("#KoGridContainer").get(0));
//        }

       ko.applyBindings(self.ViewModel);
```

Of course it is not entire file. I have just put my view model and bindings there. Now, the most interesting fact is that console has not errors at all and on top of that it has also shown me the grid 3-4 times. I am sad to say "Randomly". I was seriously not able to track down the circumstances under which it used to show up but it has shows me grid 1% of time. Other 99% no grid at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: A little update on this. I copied and pasted the code from Fiddle into my environment and it again failed to show the Grid. This is absolutely something strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied the code exactly from fiddle , then I can think of only one problem.. i.e; ***file reference error***  .. How does your script tags look like.. ??

Also hit the F12 button in the browser and check the errors you see..

Comment: Hi,I am sorry I was little too quick on posting last comment. I had to change my bindings to something like: `if ($("#KoGridContainer").length == 1) {
                    $.consolelog("found Ko-Grid");
                    ko.applyBindings(self.viewModel, $("#KoGridContainer").get(0));
                }`. This is because of a lot of bindings are happening through the application and there are a lot of view models. I have to bind it to a specific element all the times.

Comment: Actually whil etrying to bind a specific element, my fiddler also does nto work check this: http://jsfiddle.net/sf4p3/37/

Comment: OK. The problem is resolved. Here is the reason of the problem: I am in AMD environment and every file has to comply to AMD(Require.js) standards. In order to achieve that I put my Ko-Grid file into `require(["order!jquery",'order!knockout',!domready], function($,ko)  {` format. Now if you have noteced the !domready element, it was the culprit. It plays a role of not running any script until all the elements are not loaded. Something like $(document.ready(function(){})). In this case, as soon as I removed !domready from the ko-Grid file, it started showing up. Thank you so much.